# Can't get into GRUB with 2 drives installed after changing mainboard

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I used to use dual drive (SSD mSATA+HDD) with Dual OS on SSD (Ubuntu+Windows 10) and my main boot loader is Ubuntu's GRUB.

Yesterday I just got back my laptop from repair center due to broken USB, so they change my mainboard. With this new mainboard I can't open up anything when I install both SSD and HDD. It's just show blank screen, not entering GRUB, but when I remove HDD it works fine.

I've tried boot-repair, change etc/default/grub or even reinstalling Ubuntu but it's still the same. When I holding 'Shift' it stuck at GRUB loading.